# Filter ListView with editText giving StaleDataException

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have this code where I am filtering results in the ListView backed by a CursorAdapter.

This is the databaseHelper method:

```
public Cursor getCategoryCursor(String constraints){

    Cursor c = null;
    if(constraints=="")
    c=database.query("categoryTable", null , null, null, null, null, "category_name COLLATE NOCASE ASC");

    else
        c=database.rawQuery("SELECT category_name,_id FROM categoryTable WHERE category_name LIKE '%"+constraints+"%'", null);
    return c;
}
```

After defining this method, I setup the onTextChangeListener on the EditText as follows:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ListView cLV=(ListView)InteractiveVoucher.this.findViewById(R.id.category_list);
    CursorAdapter filterAdapter=(CursorAdapter)cLV.getAdapter();
    filterAdapter.getFilter().filter(arg0.toString());
}
```

Finally, when i run the code I get the error on this line in the adapterCalss:

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
            //get the error on getColumnIndex() line
    tv.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(mColumnName)));
    tv.setTextSize(20);
```

Comment: Post your whole logcat please. Also show some more code of your `bindView` method class.

Comment: this is the entire bindView method. Also, i cannot post images of the logcat(dont have enough reputation). But, i am starting to think that my sql rawquery is not correct as it is not giving me the desired results. Plz check it